# Loading TinyMCE plugins with Symfony, Webpack and Encore

Tags: symfony, webpack, tinymce, webpack-encore

There are a couple of issues with TinyMCE's NPM refurbishment. I am aware of that.

I had a working version using simple `<script>` tags, but I'm stubborn and I've got my mind set on getting their NPM package to work.

**SETUP**

*Installation*

> yarn add tinymce
>
> └─ tinymce@4.8.4

*webpack.config.js*

```js
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
//...

Encore
    .setOutputPath(folder+'/public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // the usual stuff...
    // This is where tinymce lives in my code
    .addEntry('inputManager', './assets/js/inputManager.js')
    // This plugin copies all tinymce assets to the build folder
    .addPlugin(new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        {
            from:'assets/js/tinymce/themes/',
            to: 'tinymce/themes/'
        },
        {
            from: 'assets/js/tinymce/plugins/',
            to: 'tinymce/plugins/'
        },
        {
            from:'assets/js/tinymce/langs/',
            to: 'tinymce/langs/'
        }
    ]))
```

*inputManager.js*

SKIP THIS: Don't worry too much about this class. The only important thing to notice is that tinymce is imported at line 1. It works :)

```js
import './tinymce/tinymce.min'

let fullTinyMCEInit = null;

class AppControls {
    constructor() {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            appControls.initTinyMCE(); // Initialize all tinymce elements
        });

        // I'll be the judge of where you should look!
        tinymce.baseURL = location.origin + '/build/tinymce';
        // The jquery plugin doesn't work. this does.
        $.fn.tinymce = function() {
            appControls.initTinyMCE($(this));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get the tinymce configuration in a Singleton fashion
     */
    get tinyMCEConfig() {
        if (!fullTinyMCEInit) {
            fullTinyMCEInit = {
                theme_url: '/build/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js',
                language: _locale,
                plugins: [
                    "autoresize",
                    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor",
                    "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                    "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help"
                ],
                // Other config parameters (irrelevant)
            }
        }
        return fullTinyMCEInit;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize tinymce for each textarea with a class ".tinymce"
     * @param targetContainer containing elements (or itself) to initialise
     */    
    initTinyMCE(targetContainer = null) {
        const config = appControls.tinyMCEConfig;
        let targets = [];

        // reset target and selector
        config.target = null;
        config.selector = null;

        if (targetContainer) { // Container is optional
            targetContainer = $(targetContainer);
            targets = targetContainer.hasClass('tinymce') ? targetContainer : targetContainer.find('textarea.tinymce');
        } else { // No container, look in the content-wrapper
            targets = $('#content-wrapper').find('textarea.tinymce');
        }

        // Iterate targets and initialise tinymce
        $.each(targets, function(index, target) {
            config.target = target;
            tinymce.init(config);
        });
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM 1**

Tinymce loads, but throws a 404 error for each of the plugins, theme and language files it requires.

**SOLUTION 1**

I created a simple controller, without unnecessary imports just to return files requested as fast as possible

```php
class AssetsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Main page for the admin portal
     * Matches /build/tinymce
     * @Route(
     *     "/build/tinymce/{_type}/{_name}/{_file}",
     *     name="get_tinymce_assets",
     *     requirements={
     *         "_type": "plugins|langs|skins",
     *         "_name": "\w+",
     *         "_file": ".+"
     *     }
     * )
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function getTinyMCEAssets(
        $_type,
        $_name,
        $_file
    ) {
        // NPM package contains minified js files, but still looks for unminified versions
        $minifiedFile =
            strpos($_file, '.min.') === false
                ? str_replace('.css', '.min.css', str_replace('.js', '.min.js', $_file))
                : $_file;

        return $this->file(
            'build/tinymce/'.
            $_type.'/'.
            $_name.'/'.
            $minifiedFile);
    }
}
```

This works, the tinymce editor loads!

**PROBLEM 2**

[image]

It takes 8 SECONDS!!! for each file to be retrieved!
You can understand why this is not acceptable, especially since the loading doesn't happen asynchronously.

Any insight you might have will be appreciated. If you're still reading this of course :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import each plugin you want to load via the module loading process.  We have documentation regarding this here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/usage-with-module-loaders/

Comment: Yes I read that and tried that. I actually have the plugin imports commented out in my code. I don't remember what exactly was wrong. let me check

Comment: Ok... great... hmmm... never mind! I uncommented the imports and commented the route and it just... works! I believe it was complaining about some minified files and language files not being found. I'll keep using it for a while and let you know if one of the issues reappear. Thanks!